# Perl RegEx error

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I am currently trying to create a log parser that takes from an input file (a .log) a series of ping reports in the following format: (64 bytes from 194.12.224.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=66.7 ms) and builds an output file (a .csv).

After numerous attempts, I hit the below error. My workmate gave me his code (below), which is written differently but is in essence the same. His code gives the same error, although his, naturally, works just fine at the same task. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

I now believe my first two regex's work ok, the third is the problem.  Below is what I am attempting to parse:

120 packets transmitted, 120 received, 0% packet loss, time 119247ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 65.944/67.381/72.714/1.728 ms

My first post on here, apologies if something is missing.

```
$INPUT  = "ping.log";
$OUTPUT = "pingParsed.csv";

# > operator puts the write function in overwrite mode rather than append.
open (INPUT, '<', $INPUT);
open (OUTPUT, '>', $OUTPUT);

while (<INPUT>) {

# if (timestamp regex)
if(/(\w{3})\s+(\w{3})\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s+GMT\s+(\2013)/) {


# print OUTPUT (date regex variables, $1 = Day, $2 = Month, $3 = Day, $4 = hour, $7 = year)
print OUTPUT "$1 , $2 , $3 , $4 , $7";

$headers = "IP, Seq, Time";

print OUTPUT "$headers";

}

# if (ping info regex, $1 = IP address, $2 = Seq, $3 = Time)
if ( m/icmp_seq=
(\S+)
\s+ttl=
(\S+)
\s+time=
(\S+) /x) # x allows use of whitespaces and comments in the regex.
{
    print "$1, $2, $3\n";
}


# if (regex for total ping info - I think this is line 55.) 
if (/\d+\d+\d+\s+\packets\s+\transmitted,\s+\d+\d+\d+\s+\received,\s+(\d+)\s+\packet\s+\loss,\s+time\s+(\d+)\ms\s+\min\avg\max\mdev\s+=\s+(\(S+)\\/\(S+)\\/(S+)\\/\(\S+)\s+\ms/) {
headers: 
print ("$15 = packet loss(%), $22 = time(ms), $28 = rttmin, $33 = arg, $35 = max, $37 = ndev");

print OUTPUT ($15, $22, $28, $33, $35, $37);

 } 


}

close $INPUT;
close $OUTPUT;
```

Error:

```
Backslash found where operator expected at ./pingParseScript.pl line 55, near "/\d+\d+\d+\s+\packets\s+\transmitted
    (Missing operator before \?)
```

Backslash found where operator expected at ./pingParseScript.pl line 55, near ")\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
Backslash found where operator expected at ./pingParseScript.pl line 55, near ")\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at ./pingParseScript.pl line 55, near "/\d+\d+\d+\s+\packets\s+\transmitted,\s+\d+\d+\d+\s+\received,\
Substitution pattern not terminated at ./pingParseScript.pl line 55.

Comment: I think there's an unmatched delimiter earlier in the program. Do you have a sub called `s`, `m` or `y` by any chance?

Comment: You only showed one line, but the messages show errors in two lines.

Comment: Note that errors in an `elsif` expression can have the line number of the `if` in the error message.

Comment: The code you did show is syntactically fine (if you ignore the missing EXPR that should precede or BLOCK that should follow, neither of which would give those errors).

Comment: Please, show us the complete code, or a relevant fragment. The error reported references two lines: 43 and 58

Comment: curly braces are missing after if statement

Comment: Error which you wrote is complete?and which is line 55?

Comment: remove backslash before transmitted

Comment: Still giving me the same error unfortunately. Line 55 is the 'if (/\d+\d+\d+\s+\packets\s+\transmitted,\s+\d+\d+\d+\s+\received,\s+(\d+)\s+\packet\s+\loss,\s+time\s+(\d+)\ms\s+\min\avg\max\mdev\s+=\s+(\(S+)\\/\(S+)\\/(S+)\\/\(\S+)\s+\ms/) {'

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

1) Change `while(INPUT)` by `while (<INPUT>)`

2) The last if must include `{}` and the regexp memories are restarted (from `$1`)

```
if(/icmp_seq=(\S+)\s+ttl=(\S+)\s+time=(\S+)/) {
   print OUTPUT "$1, $2, $3"; 
}
```

Also, use lexical file handles, in a modern-perl way:

```
open my $input_fh, '<', $INPUT or die $!;
open my $output_fh, '>', $OUTPUT or die $!;

while( <$input_fh> ) {
   # ...
}


close $input_fh;
close $output_fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are missing after if statement, it should be written like this:

```
if(/icmp_seq=(\S+)\s+ttl=(\S+)\s+time=(\S+)/)
{

#if(/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+icmp_seq=(\S+)\s+ttl=\d+\s+time=(\S+)/)


print OUTPUT "$8, $10, $16"; 
}
```

Or this:

```
print OUTPUT "$8, $10, $16"
    if(/icmp_seq=(\S+)\s+ttl=(\S+)\s+time=(\S+)/);
```

Also

```
while (INPUT)
```

should be written like this:

```
while (<INPUT>)
```

Replace your if statement with this:

```
if( /icmp_seq=
(\S+)
\s+ttl=
(\S+)
\s+time=
(\S+)/x ) #x allows use of whitespaces and comments in your regex
{
    print "$1, $2, $3\n"; 
}
```

Comment: I have corrected the mistakes as you've suggested, however still getting the 'Backslash found where operator expected at line X near ")\"error message relating to the regular expression.

Comment: That particular backslash, whether present or nor does not alter the error message unforunately.

Comment: why're you using $8, $9, $16?They're not filled! use $1, $2, $3 instead.

Comment: I've changed those too, they were left over from my previous and also failed implementation!

Comment: @OliverBroad I've edited my answer. It's just for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: One more thing, I noticed, your regular expression won't give IP address

Comment: I'm still getting four instances of the 'Backslash found where operator expected at ./pingParseScript.pl line 55, near ")\"
        (Missing operator before \?)' error. Although your implementation of the regex looks much better than mine, thank you.

Comment: I've updated the post to more clearly show which line I mean, it's the third regular expression. I hadn't realised it did not show when I posted the problem. I think the first two regex's are ok now, thank you.